# Remove white border around fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem when i try to display a listview in my fragment, it seems like there is a white border around the fragment. I also have a similar listview displayed in an activity and it matches perfectly with the borders of the screen.
I'm gonna post below the xml file and a screenshot I took of the fragment, I hope you can help me out.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- displays the loading animation while downloading the listview -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_benvenuto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Ecco l'elenco completo dei libri a catalogo."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_benvenuto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Benvenuto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="@string/empty_dashboard"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Image of my fragment problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKwuy.png)

Comment: check your activity layout you might give padding in the root layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Listview` is inheriting the `Benvenuto Textview's` margins as it's set to aling it. Put the views in a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Benvenuto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_benvenuto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Ecco l'elenco completo dei libri a catalogo."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried like you said but unfortunately it doesn't change. Any other ideas?

Comment: The same white border as before, I've also tried to convert all my xml in a Linear layout but it didn't work out

Comment: Can you post your root xml, the one holding the fragment

Comment: Ok, I was copying my content.xml when i found out there was a padding. Once removed it worked jus fine. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you set the width and height to match-constraint I've noticed that it adds some imaginary padding like this for whatever reason. It looks like this layout is pretty simple and just linearly goes from top to bottom in terms of its views. Why don't you just use a LinearLayout instead, and set the dimensions to matchparent? That should fix it, unless you need to add more stuff to this layout.